# How to select columns of data in BigQuery that has all NULL values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to select columns of data in BigQuery that has all NULL values

```
A          B          C 
NULL       1           NULL
NULL       NULL        NULL
NULL       2           NULL
NULL       3           NULL
```

I want to retrieve columns A and C. Please can you help!!

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: apparently BigQuery, given the title

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on my comment on Mikhail's answer, this is what I had in mind. It doesn't require generating a query string, which could be quite long if you have a large number of columns. It compares the count of null values for each column name to the total number of rows in the table to decide if the column should be included in the result.

```
    #standardSQL
    WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
      SELECT NULL A,  1 B,  NULL C  UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    NULL, NULL    UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    2,    NULL    UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    3,    NULL 
    )
    SELECT null_column
    FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t,
      UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t),
        r'\"([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\":null')
      ) AS null_column
    GROUP BY null_column
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project.dataset.table`);
```

Comment: love this one. jealous a little that i got wrong direction here and missed this one :o) definitelly voted! really cool power of BigQuery Standard SQL!!!

Comment: Thanks! :) It makes me want to provide more reflection-type functionality in BigQuery...it opens up a lot of cool query patterns.

Comment: totally agree! more & more cool examples like this one would unlock the built-in power for many users to use!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant:- Thank you and appreciate your help!!

Comment: @ElliottBrossard: THank you Sir!!

Comment: it is important on SO to accept answer you liked most and vot up answers that were helpful. please consider!

Answer (score 2):

Below is  for BigQuery StandardSQL

Simple option:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT NULL A,  1 B,  NULL C  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    NULL, NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    2,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    3,    NULL 
)
SELECT COUNT(A) A, COUNT(B) B, COUNT(C) C
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

it returns below where 0(zero) indicates that respective column has all NULLs

```sql
A   B   C    
0   3   0
```

If this is "not enough" - below is more "sophisticated" version:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT NULL A,  1 B,  NULL C  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    NULL, NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    2,    NULL    UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,    3,    NULL 
)
SELECT SPLIT(y, ':')[OFFSET(0)] column
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{}"]', '') x
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(A) A, COUNT(B) B, COUNT(C) C
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ) t
), UNNEST(SPLIT(x)) y
WHERE CAST(SPLIT(y, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) = 0
```

it returns result as below - enlisting only columns with all NULLs

```sql
column   
A    
C
```

Note: for your real table  - just remove WITH block and replace `project.dataset.table` with your real table reference

Also, of course, use real column names

> My table has round 700 columns..

Below is an example of how you can easily generate above query for any number of columns.

**1**. Just run below
**2**. Copy result - this is a generated query
**3**. paste generated query into new UI and run it
**4**. Enjoy (I hope you will) result :o)

Of course, as usually replace `project.dataset.table` with your real table reference

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CONCAT('''
SELECT SPLIT(y, ':')[OFFSET(0)] column
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{}"]', '') x
  FROM (  
    SELECT ''', y, 
  '''
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ) t
), UNNEST(SPLIT(x)) y
WHERE CAST(SPLIT(y, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) = 0  
  '''
  )
FROM (
  SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT('COUNT(', x, ') ', x), ', ') y
  FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{}]', ''), r'"([\w_]+)":') x
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
    LIMIT 1
  ), UNNEST(x) x
)
```

Note: please pay attention to query cost - both "generation query" and final query itself will do full scan

You can generate columns list much cheaper off of [table schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource) in any [client of your choice](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

To test / play with it  - you can use same dummy data as for initial queries in my answer

Comment: My table has round 700 columns.. so that's what I am thinkng

Comment: you have not indicated this in your question :o( - so definitely writing 700 COUNTs is not applicable. but you can easily generate above script with all your columns involved. :o) try!

Comment: It's probably possible to use TO_JSON_STRING directly on the table's rows and then extract the columns that have values using a regex, right? The final piece would be to subtract that from the complete column list somehow :)

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - I think this is exactly what I just updated answer with :o) - so yes - agree

Comment: Pretty cool! I also added an answer for what I had in mind, which is a little different.