# How to select columns of data in BigQuery that has all non-NULL values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I found this question on here: [How to select columns of data in BigQuery that has all NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819678/how-to-select-columns-of-data-in-bigquery-that-has-all-null-values)
but I would like to do the opposite and find all the columns with non-null values. How would I flip this previous solution to accomplish the opposite? I am not that familiar with regexp syntax and I couldn't figure out a solution trying to research this online.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The script of [How to select columns of data in BigQuery that has all NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819678/how-to-select-columns-of-data-in-bigquery-that-has-all-null-values)
can be modified as following:

```
    WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
      SELECT 77 A,  1 B,  NULL C  UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    6, NULL    UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    2,    NULL    UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL,    3,    NULL 
    )
    SELECT all_column,  count(null_column) as count_null, count(1) as total_rows
    FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t,
        UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t),
        r'\"([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\":')
      ) AS all_column
      left join       UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t),
        r'\"([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\":null')
      ) AS null_column
 on null_column=all_column
    GROUP BY 1
   HAVING count(null_column)=count(1)
```

The `TO_JSON_STRING` converts each entry to following string `column_name:value`.
The `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL( ... , r'\"([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\":')` extract from that string the column name.

if the value is null.

Comment: When I run that query, this is the output I get:
Row  all_column  count_null  total_rows  
1        C                       4                      4

The output I am hoping to see from the example is:
column_with_data
A
B